# How to access a web service that requires authetication

Tags: r, web-applications, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading information from a password protected site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420506/reading-information-from-a-password-protected-site)

I have a webservice that provides data in csv form, based on the url you use to access it.  i.e. `http://sever.com/parameter1` returns a csv for parameter 1, `http://sever.com/parameter1` returns a csv for parameter 2, etc.  When I first access the site in my browser, I type in a username and password and can then access any data I want.

The problem arises when I try to import that data into R.  I tried this function:

```
readLines('http://sever.com/parameter1')
```

But got the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open: HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'
```

Of course, this is because R doesn't know to pass my username and password along with the request.  How do I define these additional parameters in R?  Is there any way to add a cookie to the request or something?

Thank you.

/edit: The answer here (different question wording wasn't picked up by SO) worked for me:

[Reading information from a password protected site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420506/reading-information-from-a-password-protected-site)

If anyone else has any other advice, please let me know.

Comment: What sort of authentication is being used? Apache or some PHP or similar script accepting POST or GET?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: The site simply asks for a username and password.  Ammending my url to: `readLines('http://user:pass@sever.com/parameter1')` worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use curl to grab the file?  That way you can set http headers for username and password:

```
curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
```

There is a curl library for R

```
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/r/
```