# R - Copy generated URL to download file

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping

I am attempting to download some files from a website where I have a login. I am able to generate the list of file URLs but simply logging in from my browser and using `download.file` in R does not scrape the file.

I tried the solution presented here ([Reading information from a password protected site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420506/reading-information-from-a-password-protected-site)), but it also did not work in R or directly from the browser as it sent me back to the login page.

I did notice that if I am logged in and click on the generated links to each of the files, I get sent to a new URL related to that file. If I copy this new link into the URL input of `download.file`, I am able to download the file from within R.

My question is if there is a method to copy this redirected URL into R so that I am able to automate the downloading? I can directly access the URL with `browseURL`, but I cannot bring back this new URL into R.

If there is another more efficient way to access data that requires a login from R, I am also happy to be linked to this.

Thanks!

Comment: RSelenium is magical.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388974/how-do-i-use-cookies-with-rcurl) may be related.