# Extract JSON response from a website in R

Tags: r, json

I am trying to get information from this link, it is in JSON format

```
http://data.fidessa.com/FragPro2/fragBreakdown?fim=EPRE.PA&start=20180801&end=20180810&global=Y&format=json
```

However, I keep getting an error to get response from the link

> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Here is my code:

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "http://data.fidessa.com/FragPro2/fragBreakdown?fim=EPRE.PA&start=20180801&end=20180810&global=Y&format=json"
data <- fromJSON(url)
```

---

(update) I find out that I need to stay in the browser which I log in to Fidessa to make the link work. Is there any way that I can send my log in information to Fidessa and get data from the link ?

Comment: Is fidessa behind a paywall? I received an access denied when visiting the url provided, also i can't seem to navigate to fidessa.com in general.

Comment: Yep, it is fidessa. However, you do not need to pay anything, just register a free account and you have an access.

Answer (score 0):

could data you are looking for does not exist anymore. I took other url and your code is working

```
url <- "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo"
  fromurl <- fromJSON(url)
```

Comment: The data still exists. I see that I need to stay on the browser which I log in to Fidessa to make the link work.

Comment: it is password protected site. you can use some of the approaches from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420506/reading-information-from-a-password-protected-site. However it is still to be checked whether site connection could be with authentification