# How to download a csv requiring login in R

Tags: r, csv, download

To be blunt, I want to download the contents of https://www.myfxbook.com/statements/2531687/statement.csv

Thing is, when I try to download it into R (base package), the function returns an statement requesting login:

```
> url = "https://www.myfxbook.com/statements/2531687/statement.csv"
> download.file(url, destfile = "temp")
trying URL 'https://www.myfxbook.com/statements/2531687/statement.csv'
Content type 'text/csv' length unknown
downloaded 48 bytes
> readLines("temp")
[1] "Please login to Myfxbook.com to use this feature"
```

I tried GET from httr and got the same result:

```
> GET(url, authenticate(user, pass), content_type("text/csv"), write_disk("temp"))
> readLines("temp")
[1] "Please login to Myfxbook.com to use this feature"
```

This also failed:

```
> library(RCurl)
> baseurl = "https://www.myfxbook.com/statements/2531687/statement.csv"
> un = ***** # masked
> pw = ***** # masked
> upw = paste(un, pw, sep = ":")
> webpage = getURL(baseurl, userpwd = upw)
> webpage
[1] "Please login to Myfxbook.com to use this feature"
```

I have login info, I just don't know how to use it to download the file.

How can I get it done?

Thanks!

Comment: What code did you use to download the file?

Comment: Should have mentioned, sorry. I tried base R, with some authentication options (it was actually a while ago). Today I tried Rcurl which let me authenticate in the main page (www.myfxbook.com), but I could not get the file from there.

Comment: Please provide the line of code that did not work as part of your question.

Comment: I got more specific up there.

Comment: Have you tried this previous post [Reading information from a password protected site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5420506/4752675)

Comment: No success. Why do they make it so hard? >:(

Answer (score 0):

I tried that CSV and I didn't see anything at all.  Anyway, this is how you would normally do it (using another example).

```
library(dplyr)
MyData2 <- read.csv(file="http://www.grex.org/~ev/breweries_geocode.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: I guess you must be logged in to see the contents. Anyway:

`baseurl = "https://www.myfxbook.com/statements/2531687/statement.csv"`

`library(dplyr)`

`data = read.csv(baseurl)`

`data`

`[1] Please.login.to.Myfxbook.com.to.use.this.feature`